# Dual 2560x1440 resolution problem

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have 2 2560x1440 displays (HP ZR2740w), and a GeForce GT610 card with two dual dvi outputs and 1GB of RAM.  I can get full resolution on either screen and 1/4 on the other but not full resolution on both.

When I use nvidia-settings, the problem appears to trace down to "Connection link: Single" on the second DVI port (DFP-1).  I've experimented with swapping connections at the card, which results in swapping which monitor has full resolution.  Consequently, the problem cannot be in the monitor or in the DVI cable.

Is this a case of "you lose because your video card doesn't truly support two dual dvi connections"?  Or am I missing something?

I'm posting outputs of various diagnostics below.

-John

```
2:33PM humpty-6: xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   1280x720       59.9  
DVI-I-3 connected 720x1280+2560+160 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1280x720       59.9*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


Portions of /var/log/Xorg.0.log   
[    10.041] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.116  Mon Oct 28 20:59:08 PDT 2013
[    10.041] Loading extension GLX
[    10.041] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    10.041] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    10.041] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    10.041] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    10.057] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    10.072] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.116  Mon Oct 28 20:40:38 PDT 2013
[    10.072] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    10.086] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    10.086] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    10.086] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    10.086] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    10.086] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    10.086] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "True"
[    10.086] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    10.970] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (HP ZR2740w (DFP-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    10.970] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    10.981] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (HP ZR2740w (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision
[    10.981] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     stereo.
[    10.983] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 610 (GF119) at PCI:7:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    10.983] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    10.983] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 75.19.55.00.12
[    10.983] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    10.983] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GT 610 at PCI:7:0:0
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0):     HP ZR2740w (DFP-0) (connected)
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0):     HP ZR2740w (DFP-1) (connected)
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): HP ZR2740w (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): HP ZR2740w (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link TMDS
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): HP ZR2740w (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): HP ZR2740w (DFP-1): Internal Single Link TMDS
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    10.989] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal Single Link TMDS
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for  display
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device HP ZR2740w (DFP-0) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device HP ZR2740w (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has been
[    10.989] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.)
[    10.989] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    10.989] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    10.989] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    10.989] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    10.989] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    10.989] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[    10.989] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3840 x 1440
[    11.024] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (108, 107); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    11.024] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    11.025] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    11.025] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    11.025] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    11.033] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select,DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
[    11.076] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    11.127] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    11.127] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    11.127] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    11.128] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    11.128] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    11.129] Loading extension XINERAMA
[    11.129] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    11.129] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    11.129] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    11.129] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    11.129] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    11.129] (--) RandR disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your card.  It can only handle 1x dual link dvi at full resolution, the second is single link dvi.  1 gb or ram is not enough to push 2560x1440 on 2 monitors.  This is why you are only getting it on 1 monitor.  The card can drive 2 monitors at 1920*1080 just fine but you are not going to get 2 at 2560*1440.

2*(1920*1080)= 4,147,200  normal setup which it can do

1*(2560*1600) = 4,096,000 (this is the max for that card)

1.25*(2560*1440) =4,608,000 this is what you are seeing on your setup.  which is too much for your card.

Your card can't support 2 monitors at max resolution and no the spec sheets you look up on the websites and purchase sites don't adequately explain this.

Question.

Comment: This calculation is absurd. `1*(2560*1600) = 4,096,000` = 4 million pixels. Let's assume you needs 24 bits (=3 bytes) to encode the colors for each pixel. The total memory required = 4M x 3 = 12 MB = 0.012 GB. How come 1GB is not enough?